# Spring Boot - Building a RESTful Web Service with MySql access

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-boot

I send a request to the rest-api to store a object into mysql database.

Which step is missing that i can store via Jpa the objects into my database?

*Here is the Rest-Controller*

```
@RestController
public class OwnerRestController {
    @Autowired
    private final OwnerRestRepository repo;

    public OwnerRestController(OwnerRestRepository repo) {this.repo = repo;}

    @RequestMapping(value="/owner/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Owner create(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body){
        Owner o = new Owner();
        o.setFirstName(body.get("firstName"));
        o.setLastName(body.get("lastName"));
        o.setAddress(body.get("address"));
        o.setCity(body.get("city"));
        o.setTelephone(body.get("telephone"));
        this.repo.save(o);
        return o;
    }
}
```

*Here is the Repository Interface*

```
public interface OwnerRestRepository extends CrudRepository<Owner,integer>{}
```

*Here is the JSON-Object Owner*

```
{
    "firstName":"fname",
    "lastName":"lname",
    "address":"address1",
    "city":"city1",
    "telephone":"4711"
}
```

*Server Response*

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "firstName": "fname",
    "lastName": "lname",
    "address": "address1",
    "city": "city1",
    "telephone": "4711"
}
```

What's wrong in the code that the data can't be stored in the database?

Best regards, Mux

Comment: The objects are stored locally at runtime environment but not in the database.

Comment: So your question is: is it possible to store data in memory? Yes, of course it is. It's probably not a good idea, and you need to make it thread-safe, but sure, it's possible.

Comment: I could solve this issue to put these entries in application.properties file:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://anyurltodatabse
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pwd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `Spring` runs the in-memory database - `H2`, so your items only exist when your application is running.
To persist your data you need to configure the application to use another database.

To query `H2` you can also use [The H2 Console Application](http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html)

For example if you want to configure `MySQL` you should have add following configuration options to your `application.properties` file.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

In case your are using `application.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
    username: dbuser
    password: dbpass
```